# how to align radio box text expand scroll to downward

Tags: flutter, dart

Radio Box i want

[image]

so this what radio box and the text align i want to make, but this is what i get and i don't find any solution what else to do to change it to be like the first image

My Radio Box

[image]

```
 Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: termsOption.map(
                      (e) {
                        var index = termsOption.indexOf(e);
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                height: 0,
                                child: Radio(
                                  materialTapTargetSize:
                                      MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                  value: index,
                                  groupValue: radioValue,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    print(e['value']);
                                    setState(() {
                                      radioValue = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 5),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  e['value'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need update

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

with

`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`

and also instead of

`margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),`

write

`margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),`

Comment: if i use your code the second radio is not parallel with the text

Comment: Are you sure!?!? I copied your code and I've tried that. Everything went Ok. 'crossAxisAlignment' in Row widget, only adjust its contents vertically.